# How to change just one column in a txt file leaving all else the same and respecting the whitespaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a file with a lot of rows. To safe space, I am just c/p in a sense that gives the shape of my file.

```
| Martini system from 2b97.pdb                 |
| 55601                                        |
|     1ALA     BB    1  13.904   5.512   1.259 |
|    12VAL     BB   12   4.199  35.292  21.353 |
|   112VAL    SCC  113   4.367   5.234  21.445 |
|  1113CYS     BB 1114   4.041   4.969  21.220 |
| 11113CYS    SCC11115   4.088  14.816  21.041 |
| 19293DEC      C55598  19.018   0.828   7.094 |
|   9.05570   9.05570  30.02670                |
```

I need to add 0.1 units to the last column.

Therefore, my output file should look exactly like this:

```
| Martini system from 2b97.pdb                 |
| 55601                                        |
|     1ALA     BB    1  13.904   5.512   1.359 |
|    12VAL     BB   12   4.199  35.292  21.453 |
|   112VAL    SCC  113   4.367   5.234  21.545 |
|  1113CYS     BB 1114   4.041   4.969  21.320 |
| 11113CYS    SCC11115   4.088  14.816  21.141 |
| 19293DEC      C55598  19.018   0.828   7.194 |
|   9.05570   9.05570  30.02670                |
```

The most important thing is that my output file should have exactly the same whitespaces, format and dtype. Everything in this file is a string.

If whitespaces, format and dtype are not respected then I cannot use the output file to run in the program I need.

Just in case, I do not need to keep the initial file (although I think this part is irrelevant for me to add).

Thanks for your help.
I have tried but my problem is that I cannot keep the same shape with python.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to other answers, but here's another option. String reversing done to do the string replace right->left.

```
with open('in.txt', 'r') as fi, open('out.txt', 'w') as fo:
    fo.write(fi.readline())
    fo.write(fi.readline())

    for line in fi.readlines():
        try:
            old = line[-10:-3]
            new = '{:>7.3f}'.format(float(old) + 0.1)
            line = line[::-1].replace(old[::-1], new[::-1], 1)[::-1]
        except ValueError as _:
            pass
        finally:
            fo.write(line)
```

Comment: float math can be inaccurate, I would recommend using the decimal library

Comment: @ananvodo hmm, works for me, I get your expected output in python 2.7 and 3.5

Comment: @TheDavidFactor true, but it's fine to 3 decimal places

Answer (score 3):

Like another answer, I would use string slicing to get just the final column, and string concatenation to put the line back together again. However, I would use `decimal.Decimal` for the fixed-point math:

```
import fileinput
import decimal
import sys

files = ['x.txt']

for line in fileinput.input(files, inplace=True):
    number = line[38:46]
    try:
        number = decimal.Decimal(number)
        number += decimal.Decimal('.1')
        number = '{:8}'.format(number)
        line = line[:38] + number + line[46:]
    except decimal.InvalidOperation:
        pass
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: I tested it and it put everything in just one row.
Martini system from 2b97.pdb  is ok.
 55601 is ok too.
from then on, everything was pasted in only one row

Answer (score 1):

I also used decimal math and string slicing. Here's my version:

```
from decimal import Decimal, InvalidOperation

def add_zero_point_one(data):
    new_data = []
    for l in data.split('\n'):
        try:
            d = Decimal(l[38:46]) + Decimal('0.1')
            l = l[:38] + str(d).rjust(8) + l[46:]
        except InvalidOperation:
            pass
        new_data.append(l)
    return '\n'.join(new_data)
```

This worked with the provided sample, but assumes:

1. That all data out in slice 38:46 is column data you want to increment
2. That the column widths are fixed

Here's my full working sample:

```
from decimal import Decimal, InvalidOperation

data = '''| Martini system from 2b97.pdb                 |
| 55601                                        |
|     1ALA     BB    1  13.904   5.512   1.259 |
|    12VAL     BB   12   4.199  35.292  21.353 |
|   112VAL    SCC  113   4.367   5.234  21.445 |
|  1113CYS     BB 1114   4.041   4.969  21.220 |
| 11113CYS    SCC11115   4.088  14.816  21.041 |
| 19293DEC      C55598  19.018   0.828   7.094 |
|   9.05570   9.05570  30.02670                |'''


def add_zero_point_one(data):
    new_data = []
    for l in data.split('\n'):
        try:
            d = Decimal(l[38:46]) + Decimal('0.1')
            l = l[:38] + str(d).rjust(8) + l[46:]
        except InvalidOperation:
            pass
        new_data.append(l)
    return '\n'.join(new_data)


print(data)
print(add_zero_point_one(data))
```