# Replace variables values and save in the same text file

Tags: python

I have 200 text files that contains 133 lines (first one is the header) and 9 columns each. What I am trying to do is to multiply all the values of the E-Amp and N-amp columns by 10, and replace the old values by the new ones in the same file, and save in the same format.
Here's an example of one of the files:

```
Extension/Epoch  Lat(+N,deg)  Lon(+E,deg)  E-Amp(mm)  E-Pha(deg)  N-Amp(mm)  N-Pha(deg)  V-Amp(mm)  V-Pha(deg) 
20080101000000      36.87500000      329.50000000      3.46453912      0.00000000      6.56776394      180.00000000      7.15208982      180.00000000
20080201000000      36.87500000      329.50000000      0.30411436      180.00000000      5.06292797      180.00000000      3.16756356      180.00000000
20080301000000      36.87500000      329.50000000      1.93205829      0.00000000      0.25084443      0.00000000      2.88015036      180.00000000
20080401000000      36.87500000      329.50000000      0.64129867      0.00000000      2.28822012      0.00000000      2.87279715      180.00000000
20080501000000      36.87500000      329.50000000      1.79042810      180.00000000      5.02766918      0.00000000      6.21064019      0.00000000
20080601000000      36.87500000      329.50000000      2.05377778      180.00000000      5.67777792      0.00000000      11.62667229      0.00000000
20080701000000      36.87500000      329.50000000      4.23575230      180.00000000      5.90637626      0.00000000      10.19361807      0.00000000
20080801000000      36.87500000      329.50000000      2.68562850      180.00000000      5.30434018      0.00000000      8.97660361      0.00000000
```

I tried to do the following:

```
path = 'C:/Users/User/.../folder'
file_list = glob.glob(path+'*.txt')  

for file in file_list:
    date = np.loadtxt(file,usecols=(0,),dtype='U',unpack=True,skiprows=1)       
    lat,lon,eamp,epha,namp,npha,vamp,vpha = np.loadtxt(file,delimiter=None,unpack=True,skiprows=1,usecols=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))  
    
    eamp=eamp*10
    namp=namp*10
```

But I have no ideia how to replace the values and save in the same file.
I tried this > [How to change just one column in a txt file leaving all else the same and respecting the whitespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093283/how-to-change-just-one-column-in-a-txt-file-leaving-all-else-the-same-and-respec) but it didn't work.

Any help, pls?

Comment: Generally it's much easier to write a new file, and then rename it to the old name.

Comment: You can read the file, save it in a python object, modify the python object and then rewrite the file with the modified data. Check my code in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lines = []

#Read the file and save in memory
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line.split())

#Do the modification
is_first_line = True

for line in lines:
    if is_first_line:
        is_first_line = False
        continue
        
    line[3] = str(10*float(line[3]))
    line[5] = str(10*float(line[5]))

#Rewrite the file with the modification
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:    
    for line in lines:
        print("   ".join(line), file=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

#update.
Doing for the 200 files:

```
path1='C:/Users/User/.../folder/'
path2='C:/Users/User/.../output_folder/'  

liist = os.listdir(path1)

for i in range(len(liist)):
     
    lines = []

#Read the file and save in memory
    with open(path1+liist[i], 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            lines.append(line.split())

#Do the modification
    is_first_line = True

    for line in lines:
        if is_first_line:
            is_first_line = False
            continue
        
        line[3] = str(10*float(line[3]))
        line[5] = str(10*float(line[5]))
        

#Rewrite the file with the modification      
    with open(path2+liist[i], 'w') as f:      #put the modified files in a new folder (path2)  
        for line in lines:
            print("   ".join(line), file=f)
```